# Can I use the "Other Income" section of my W4 in lieu of paying quarterly taxes on 1099-NEC income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-w-4, form-1099-misc

I was looking at a IRS [W-4 form](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf) recently and noticed that it had a section for "Other income (not from jobs)". So let's say you have a W-2 job and a 1099-NEC "job".

You're not employed, per se, with the 1099-NEC job, so could I put my expected earnings from my 1099-NEC job into the "Other income (not from jobs)" section of the W-4 in lieu of paying quarterly taxes via a 1040-ES?

Comment: Who are you giving that W4 to?

Comment: @littleadv - my current employer? Who else would I give a W-4 form too? This year I got a W-2 and a 1099-NEC. I have a regular day job through which I get health insurance and can get unemployment, in theory, if I were let go, and I have a consulting gig for which I get a 1099-NEC. They're independent of one another.

Comment: @littleadv - I updated my question to make things a little clearer hopefully

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/80569/pay-estimated-tax-using-w-4-withholding-instead-of-quarterly-payments

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The IRS doesn't care which pocket you take the money out to pay them.

If you have both a salaried (W2, as you say) job and a side contractor gig, you can most definitely adjust your salary withholding to also cover your additional tax liability from your side gig. Same goes with non-earned income (e.g.: you expect to have capital gains, or rental income, or win the lottery - you can adjust your salary withholding to cover for that).

From your question it was not immediately clear that you have this situation where you are both a salaried employee and a contractor, but from your comments you indicated that that is so.

Comment: You can definitely use withholding, but simply putting NEC (selfemployment) **in 4a will** only increase withholding to cover the increased _income_ tax (and probably a little over, if you get QBI deduction for your side business) but **not added _selfemployment_ tax** which is computed differently and doesn't match the formulas for income-tax withholding; that's why the instructions tell you to use the estimator instead for SE. 4a does work for investments, passive, and gambling, but not SE.

Answer (score 1):

Box 4a on the W-4 is labeled

> Other income (not from jobs).

And the instructions for this line say:

> Enter in this step the total of your other
> estimated income for the year, if any. You shouldn’t include
> income from any jobs or self-employment.

Contract work is a job, so I don't think you should include it there.

However, you can always use box 4c "Extra withholding" to increase your withholding so that you don't need to make estimated tax payments. The instructions for this line say:

> Enter in this step any additional tax you want
> withheld from your pay each pay period, including any
> amounts from the Multiple Jobs Worksheet, line 4.

As long as the IRS receives the appropriate amount during the year, they don't care how you label it.

Comment: Contract is not a job in that regard since you don't have tax withholding from 1099.

Comment: It's a job, it just doesn't have withholding.

Comment: Notice: *in that regard*. Withholding is what we're talking about here.

Comment: It specifically says "not from jobs". It doesn't say "not from jobs that have withholding".

Comment: If they wanted a line for all income without withholding, they would have just said that.

Comment: They did. That's the "other income" line. Not sure what you're arguing about. It explicitly says on that line: "*If you want tax withheld for other income you
expect this year that won’t have withholding*"

Comment: I'm arguing that it specifically says "not from jobs". So withholding for income from jobs should be in the "Extra withholding" line, not this line. I don't know why they said that, but I don't see why it shouldn't be taken literally.

Comment: You don't know and that's fine, but that's what they said and they said it quite explicitly.

Comment: I'm just reading the plain language of the form. It seems like lying to include job income in that line when it specifically says "not from jobs". The form provides another place to add extra withholding.

Comment: That said, the last time I filled out a W-4 form they didn't even have the "Extra income" line, I've always used the "Extra withholding" line to withhold for investment income (I've never had multiple jobs).

Comment: *If you want tax withheld for other income you expect this year that won’t have withholding* - what can be more explicit than that? Either way it doesn't matter, functionally. You can use your old proven method if you like and that's fine. Some W4 calculators do that now as well.

Comment: I've added more supporting details from the instructions page.